# What does arg mean in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Lately I have been working with an API, there I found this array called $args_something. I thought this was just some random name. A couple of days after I saw a totally different code with the same type of array which started with $args too. What does this mean. Both codes were in PHP.

An example of the array structure:

```
$args = array( 

//////Author Parameters - Show posts associated with certain author.
    //http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters
    'author' => '1,2,3,',                     //(int) - use author id [use minus (-) to exclude authors by ID ex. 'author' => '-1,-2,-3,']
    'author_name' => 'luetkemj',              //(string) - use 'user_nicename' (NOT name)
    'author__in' => array( 2, 6 ),            //(array) - use author id (available with Version 3.7).
    'author__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ),        //(a
```

I have to say both codes were originally from WordPress.

Comment: I cannot able to get your question, do you want to know the difference between `author__in` and `author__not_in` ?

Comment: The code has nothing todo with my question. Its about the name of the array. what does it stand for? @RaunakGupta

Comment: @RaunakGupta No, he wants to know what `$args` mean. If its just a randomly given name by wordpress, or if its something special. This question is one of the good understandable.. don't know why you don't understand it. Think its one of the better asked questions here.

Comment: $args just mean Arguments to pass through a function, a query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is just the naming convention which increases code readability. you can replace it with any name it won't affect your code.

**Example I:**

```
$args_user = array(
    'number' => 10
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args_user);
$users = $user_query->get_results();

//------------------------------------------

$args_post = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$posts = get_posts($args_post);
```

**Example II:**

```
$my_args_1 = array(
    'number' => 10
);
$query_1 = new WP_User_Query($my_args_1);
$data = $query_1->get_results();

//------------------------------------------

$my_args_2 = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$data = get_posts($my_args_2);
```

Both the code example I and II will have same output, but first example has a good user readability and if you have a long method/code then after seeing the variable name you can easily recognized.

Comment: Why did they choose args does this word have any specific meaning?

Comment: abbreviation of [argument](http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/argument) is _arg_ so they use `$args` to denote multiple argument.